# How to Find the $d^4p $ from the four vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

Lets assume we are given the four vector  of momentum P which can be written as:

$$p = (p_0, p_t cos\theta , p_t sin \theta , P_L ) ........(1)$$

Where $P_L$ is the longitudinal competent. The transverse component can be written as easily : $p_t ^2 = p_t cos\theta^2 + p_t sin\theta ^2$

The  differential form  I need to show $$d^4p =  1/2 \  dp_0 \ dp_L \  d p_t^2  \  d \theta ........(2)$$

I understand the $p_L$ and $p_0$ are the two component that comes from $$d^4p =    dp_0  \  dp_x \ dp_y  dp_L .....(3)$$ Therefore $dp_x \ dp_y$ has to be equal to $d p_t^2  \  d \theta$ . How?

My intention is to get the equation (2) from  equation(1) or (3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant $p_t$ and not $q_t$, we have

$$\frac{1}{2}\: d(p_t^2)\:d\theta = p_t\:dp_t\:d\theta$$

which is just the polar coordinates Jacobian.

Comment: Yes , it was $p_t$

Comment: but we have $dp_t$ in equation (3). I have updated the question.

Comment: @ComplexGuy ???

Comment: I understand how you wrote $\frac{1}{2}\: d(p_t^2)\:d\theta = p_t\:dp_t\:d\theta$, but how we can write the equation (1) or (3) by using your equation and (2).

Comment: @ComplexGuy It is the polar coordinates Jacobian! I already said this